# How to get html input placeholder value from database in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a HTML input text and place holder. I want to get a place holder value from a database but I want to do it programatically:

```
<td><input runat="server" placeholder="Title" type="text" /></td>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I just don't even know where to start here.  Are you asking about how to interrogate a DB, or how to generate HTML with C#?  You don't even have any C# in your question - are you familiar with it?  What I'm really asking is:  http://whathaveyoutried.com?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to give the input a name so that you can reference it in code behind.  Then, once you go grab the value that you want from the database you will do something like this:

```
inputName.Placeholder = DataRow[0]("TextFromDBColumnName").ToString();
```

Obviously you want to put all safeguards in place to make sure that the DataTable or DataReader you are using has data and that the value that came back from the database is not NULL, which I would safeguard against in the query or stored procedure.

Comment: I am not getting  my input name to my front-end section.Is there any special namespace for this case ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. When you declare an object in the page and tell it to runat="server" that means that the object is available on the server side when the page loads and posts back.  However, you need to name the object so you can more easily reference it.  Look at the other answer, they have more explicitly outline what you need to do on the front and back ends to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

As ammills01 said you've got to give the input an ID attribute so you can call it from code-behind:

```
<td><input ID="YourID" runat="server" placeholder="Title" type="text" /></td>
```

And then call it:

```
YourID.Placeholder = DataRow[0]("TextFromDBColumnName").ToString();
```